# HIVE : Replace string/ pattern in row if it exists else do nothing

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table A with id, name, age.

```
> id       name    age
> {20}    Joan     12 
> 3       James    12 
> 12       Jill   12
> {54}     Adam    12 
> {10}     Bill    12
```

I need to remove the {} surrounding 'id' field.
I tried this :

> translate(regexp_extract(id, '([^{]*)([^}]*)', 2), '{', '')

which works but returned a null for values with NO {}.

```
id
3
12
```

Is there way I can get the output as ???

```
id
20
3
12
54
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regexp_replace udf so as to remove the "{}"  like :

```
select regexp_replace(id, '\\{|\\}','');
```

Comment: COol.. That Worked.. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following select statement:

```
select regexp_replace(col1,'[{}]','') as replaced,col2,col3 from table_name;
```